Can we use apollo client without npm (on shopify theme basically)
I am trying to implement apollo client in our shopify theme using vanilla js. almost all the documentation and guides use npm to install the apollo client package. while on shopify we don't use npm but instead use either cdn or locally served asset files. is there a way to use apollo in this scenario? or suggest any alternate for caching.
tried both of these ways but not working
console.log("inside apollo-client.js")
// const { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql, HttpLink } = window['@apollo/client/core'];
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql, HttpLink } from "https://unpkg.com/@apollo/client@3.6.9/core/core.cjs.js"

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'https://my-shopify-store.myshopify.com/api/2023-07/graphql.json',
    headers: {
      'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': '******************'
    }
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

console.log("The client in apollo-client is: ", client)

// Make client globally accessible
window.apolloClient = client;


What does "but not working" mean? Please provide debugging details. "I am trying to implement apollo client in our shopify theme using vanilla js" This is a contradiction. Vanilla JS is JavaScript without libraries. Apollo Client is a library. You can't use a library without using libraries. "Can we use apollo client without npm ... is there a way to use apollo in this scenario?" Yes, but using NPM is much easier.

The CDN link in your question is not correct. I get Cannot find "/core/core.cjs.js" in @apollo/client@3.6.9. You can't use Common JS modules in a browser without a bundler. Browsers don't understand CommonJS.

Yes, but you need an import map for that, since @apollo/client has dependencies on other projects and just importing from a CDN, your browser wouldn't know how to resolve these.
For that, you can use something like the JSPM import map generator which will generate something like this for you:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <!--
    JSPM Generator Import Map
    Edit URL: https://generator.jspm.io/#U2NhYGBkDM0rySzJSU1hcEgsyM/JyddPzslMzStxMNYzNNQzAQDhLh7AJAA
  -->
   <script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "@apollo/client": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@apollo/client@3.11.4/index.js"
    },
    "scopes": {
      "https://ga.jspm.io/": {
        "@wry/caches": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@wry/caches@1.0.1/lib/index.js",
        "@wry/context": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@wry/context@0.7.4/lib/index.js",
        "@wry/equality": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@wry/equality@0.5.7/lib/index.js",
        "@wry/trie": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@wry/trie@0.5.0/lib/index.js",
        "graphql": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:graphql@16.9.0/index.mjs",
        "graphql-tag": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:graphql-tag@2.12.6/lib/index.js",
        "optimism": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:optimism@0.18.0/lib/index.js",
        "react": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:react@18.3.1/index.js",
        "rehackt": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:rehackt@0.1.0/index.js",
        "symbol-observable": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:symbol-observable@4.0.0/lib/index.js",
        "ts-invariant": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:ts-invariant@0.10.3/lib/invariant.js",
        "tslib": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:tslib@2.6.3/tslib.es6.mjs",
        "zen-observable-ts": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:zen-observable-ts@1.2.5/module.js"
      },
      "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:optimism@0.18.0/": {
        "@wry/trie": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@wry/trie@0.4.3/lib/index.js"
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
  
  <!-- ES Module Shims import maps polyfills -->
  <script async src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.10.0/dist/es-module-shims.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script type="module">
    import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql, HttpLink }  from "@apollo/client";
  
    // Write main module code here, or as a separate file with a "src" attribute on the module script.
    console.log(ApolloClient);
  </script>
</body>
</html>

